# Setting Chinese FontName in POI HSLF

Tags: java, apache-poi, hslf

Using Apache POI HSLF to create PPT, it doesn't work when I use `rt.setFontName("黑体");`, but it works in English.

How can I make POI work with non-English-named fonts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with using APACHE-POI to convert PPT to Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687522/problem-with-using-apache-poi-to-convert-ppt-to-image)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into POI, there appeared to be a [bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55902) that contains some information about the problem you seem to have. Namely, that report also refers to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687522/problem-with-using-apache-poi-to-convert-ppt-to-image) which appears to have some possible solutions.

Lacking Excel with international fonts (or a suitably localized windows version), I cannot try this, alas. Good luck.

Comment: yes ,I identify it is a bug or a bad problem due to poi assuredly ,hehe